# apply groupby rules to timeseries?

Tags: pandas, group-by

I have a sample DataFrame as follows:

```
    value=DataFrame({'A':[0,-1,0],
                     'B':[1,1,-1],
                     'C':[0,0,1],
                     'D':[-1,1,1]})
    value.index=pd.date_range('1/1/2016',periods=len(value),freq='M')
```

And I want to have the answer as follows:

```
    answer=DataFrame({'A':[0,-1,0],
                      'B':[1,0.5,-0.5],
                      'C':[0,0,-0.5],
                      'D':[-1,0.5,1]})
    answer.index=pd.date_range('1/1/2016',periods=len(value),freq='M')
```

The rule is:

For each date, the sum of the row is zero, and the weight is equally split within each value category of `0`, `-1`, or `1`.

For example,

- If there are three -1s, one 1, then the answer is -0.33,-0.33,-0.33,1
- If there is only one 1 and three -1s, then the answer is 1,-0.33,-0.33,-0.33
- If there is two 1s, one -1, the answer is 0.5,0.5,-1,0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

value = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0,-1,0],
                 'B':[1,1,-1],
                 'C':[0,0,1],
                 'D':[-1,1,1]})
value.index = pd.date_range('1/1/2016',periods=len(value),freq='M')
pos = (value > 0)
neg = (value < 0)

result = ((value*pos).divide(pos.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
          +(value*neg).divide(neg.sum(axis=1), axis=0))

print(result)
```

yields

```
              A    B    C    D
2016-01-31  0.0  1.0  0.0 -1.0
2016-02-29 -1.0  0.5  0.0  0.5
2016-03-31  0.0 -1.0  0.5  0.5
```

Note that the last row of `result` does not match `answer`, but I think it does match the description if I understand it correctly.

---

`pos` and `neg` are boolean DataFrames. `pos`, for example, is True where `value` is positive:

```
In [206]: pos
Out[206]: 
                A      B      C      D
2016-01-31  False   True  False  False
2016-02-29  False   True  False   True
2016-03-31  False  False   True   True
```

`value*pos` is the same as `value` when `value` is positive, and zero otherwise:

```
In [207]: value*pos
Out[207]: 
            A  B  C  D
2016-01-31  0  1  0  0
2016-02-29  0  1  0  1
2016-03-31  0  0  1  1
```

`pos.sum(axis=1)` counts the number of `True` values in each row. Dividing `(value*pos)` by the count produces the desired weighting:

```
In [208]: (value*pos).divide(pos.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
Out[208]: 
              A    B    C    D
2016-01-31  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
2016-02-29  0.0  0.5  0.0  0.5
2016-03-31  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5
```

The same can be done for the negative values. Adding the positive and negative parts together yields the desired result.